# Issue merging xml output using camel pollEnrich

Tags: apache-camel

Creating XML output from various sources which need to be combine for XSLT processor but getting "No consumers available on endpoint" when using pollEnrich. The pollEnrich aggregator it not being passed the pollEnrich Exchange.

Took the aggregator out and used the default aggregator. Get the same issue. Adding logs show that there is XML output coming from the previous routes to the pollEnrich end points.

```
package com.hitrust.route;

import com.hitrust.aggregator.AddToOutput;
import com.hitrust.processor.ConvertResultToRecords;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class AuthoritativeSourceDocument extends RouteBuilder {

   public void configure() throws Exception {

    AggregationStrategy addToOutput = new AddToOutput();

    restConfiguration()
           .component("restlet")
           .host("localhost").port("18082");

    rest("/authoritativesourcedocument/{authoritativesourcedocumentid}")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
            .get()
            .to("direct:Start");

    from("direct:Start")
            .multicast()
            .to("direct:GetSections")
            .to("direct:GetTransactions")
            .to("direct:MergeSections");

    from("direct:GetSections")
            .setBody(simple("SELECT * " +
                    "  FROM [dbo].[Section] AS S" +
                    "  WHERE [Id] = ${header.id}"))
            .to("jdbc:dataSource")
            .setProperty("paramName", simple("Sections"))
            .process(new ConvertResultToRecords())
            .to("direct:GetSectionsOutput");

    from("direct:GetTransactions")
            .setBody(simple("SELECT * " +
                    "  FROM [dbo].[SectionTransaction] AS ST" +
                    "  WHERE [Id] = ${header.id}"))
            .to("jdbc:dataSource")
            .setProperty("paramName", simple("SectionTransactions"))
            .process(new ConvertResultToRecords())
            .to("direct:GetTransactionsOutput");

    from("direct:MergeSections")
            .setBody(simple("<param><id>${header.id}</id></param>"))
            .convertBodyTo(org.w3c.dom.Document.class)
            .pollEnrich("direct:GetSectionsOutput", 500, addToOutput)
            .pollEnrich("direct:GetTransactionsOutput", 500, addToOutput)
            .to("xslt:file:src/main/resources/xslts/MergeSections.xsl")


  }
}
```

To execute and have combine xml output from the last route.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use "seda:" instead of "direct:" to message from your Get* routes to pollEnrich in the MergeSections route:

```
[...]
from("direct:Start")
        .multicast()
        .to("direct:GetSections")
        .to("direct:GetTransactions")
        .to("direct:MergeSections");

from("direct:GetSections")
        .setBody(simple("SELECT * " +
                "  FROM [dbo].[Section] AS S" +
                "  WHERE [Id] = ${header.id}"))
        .to("jdbc:dataSource")
        .setProperty("paramName", simple("Sections"))
        .process(new ConvertResultToRecords())
        .to("seda:GetSectionsOutput");

from("direct:GetTransactions")
        .setBody(simple("SELECT * " +
                "  FROM [dbo].[SectionTransaction] AS ST" +
                "  WHERE [Id] = ${header.id}"))
        .to("jdbc:dataSource")
        .setProperty("paramName", simple("SectionTransactions"))
        .process(new ConvertResultToRecords())
        .to("seda:GetTransactionsOutput");

from("direct:MergeSections")
        .setBody(simple("<param><id>${header.id}</id></param>"))
        .convertBodyTo(org.w3c.dom.Document.class)
        .pollEnrich("seda:GetSectionsOutput", 500, addToOutput)
        .pollEnrich("seda:GetTransactionsOutput", 500, addToOutput)
        .to("xslt:file:src/main/resources/xslts/MergeSections.xsl")
```

Your code also looks like you assume that multicast is dispatching to the endpoints in parallel by default - it does not. You need to add the parallelProcessing() option for that.

Comment: Tried this. When adding parallelProcessing, the resource Exchange for addToOutput would be null. When not using parallelProcessing even with seda, it would come back with "No consumers available on endpoint" .